# Objective-C: initWithContentsOfURL returning null

Tags: objective-c, iphone, initwithcontentsofurl

I'm working on an app that would display a remote html and use local images, so what I'm trying to do is download the HTML of the website and display it as a "local" page, that would have access to images in my bundle.

For some reason I can't get initWithContentsOfURL to work. I checked all manuals and examples I could find and it seems that I'm doing it correctly, but the thing just won't work, returns null all the time. The same page loaded with `NSURLRequest requestWithURL` works fine.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    appURL = @"http://dragontest.fantasy-fan.org";
    notConnectedHTML = @"Could not connect.";

    NSString *seedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/seed.php", appURL]]];

    NSString *HTMLdata = @"";

    if (seedString = @"(null)") {
        NSLog(@"Can't connect on awakeFromNib.");
        HTMLdata = notConnectedHTML;
    }else {
        HTMLdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>%@%@</body>", seedString, @"<br><img src='images/Default.png'>"];
    }   
    [homeView loadHTMLString:HTMLdata baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, why aren't `appURL` and `notConnectedHTML` declared as `NSString *`? Are they declared this way elsewhere?

Secondly, you might be better off using `NSURL`'s `-urlWithString:relativeToURL:` to create the actual request URL.

Thirdly (and this is your actual problem here I suspect), to compare two C primitives, you use `==`. `=` is the assignment operator (it makes the thing on the left equal to the thing on the right). To compare two Objective-C objects, use a comparison method, like `-isEqual:` or `-isEqualToString:` (which is specifically for `NSString`s).

So instead of:

```
if (seedString = @"(null)")
```

You should use

```
if ([seedString isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
```

However I suspect the reason you're trying to compare to "(null)" is because that's what `NSLog` spits out when an object is equal to `nil`. When an object is `nil`, the object reference itself is equal to the `nil` constant, so you should use this to see if an object is `nil`:

```
if (seedString == nil)
```

Just for good measure, some people like to use this syntax which does exactly the same thing:

```
if (!seedString)
```

Comment: wow, I could have looked for 100 years and I wouldn't have looked there for a solution. thanks Nick! :) such a rookie mistake I can't believe it hehe  

I don't understand though what you mean by using `urlWithString:relativeToURL:` , how is that better/different from what I'm using?

and yes, those two vars in the beginning are global.

Comment: NSString does not qualify as a primitive, I'm afraid, but you are right that when comparing two strings == is not the best way. NSString does provide its own method for that:
if ([seedString isEqualToString:@"(null)"])

Comment: No problems!

If you store `appURL` as an `NSURL` instead of an `NSString`, you could do `[NSURL urlWithString:@"/seed.php" relativeToURL:appURL]`. Usually in Cocoa/CocoaTouch programming, you store URLs as `NSURL` objects rather than `NSString`s. The way I have just written is more readable, but will do exactly the same as what you have already.

Comment: @Elise Just to clarify - `-[NSString isEqual:]` and `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` both do the same thing when comparing two `NSString` s, but have subtle differences. You're right that I should have used `-isEqualToString:`, since as the docs say, it is faster than `-isEqual:`. The other significant difference is that `-isEqualToString:` treats accents, umlauts et. al. differently: see the `NSString` docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:).